# Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json

From a short tutorial I started this widget script to grab posts on Blogger. In the theme I originally made it in, it works fine without error. However, when I try to use the exact same code in a new template I'm working on, it throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

For the love of god I cannot figure out why it's doing that. For debugging purposes I tried removing all other scripts, placing the code right after the `<body>` tag and just before the `</body>` tag.

I really don't know anything about scripting and did this widget as a starting point in learning, but it's been months since I messed with it. Looking at it now I just don't see the problem. Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function postGrabber(json) {

        // The Magic
        for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
                    var postUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Thumbnail Stuff
            var orgImgUrl = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url ? json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url : 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mxinHrJWpBo/VD6fqbvI74I/AAAAAAAAcn8/LslulDeOROg/s72-c/noimage-chalkboard.jpg';
            var newImgUrl = orgImgUrl.replace('s72-c', 's' + imgSize + '-c');
            var imgTag = '<a class="item-link-post" href="' + postUrl + '"><img class="item-img-thumbnail" src="' + newImgUrl + '" width="' + imgSize + '" height="' + imgSize + '"/></a>';

            var authorName = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
            var authorURL = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].uri.$t;
            var authorOriImgUrl = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].gd$image.src;
            var authorNewImgUrl = authorOriImgUrl.replace('s512-c', 's' + authorImgSize + '-c');
            var authorImgTag = '<a class="item-link-author" href="' + authorURL + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="item-img-author" src="' + authorNewImgUrl + '" alt="' + authorName + '"/></a>';

            // Standard Stuff
            var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
            var postCommentCount = json.feed.entry[i].thr$total.$t;

            var postSummary = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;
            var entryShort = postSummary.substring(0, '' + summaryLength + '');
            var entryEnd = entryShort.lastIndexOf(" ");
            var postContent = entryShort.substring(0, entryEnd) + '...';

            var postDate = json.feed.entry[i].updated.$t ? json.feed.entry[i].updated.$t : json.feed.entry[i].published.$t;
            var shortDate = postDate.substring(0,10);

            // Let's Make Options Here
            var toggleImg = showImg ? '' + imgTag + '' : '';
            var toggleTitle = showTitle ? '<h1 class="item-title">' + postTitle + '</h1>' : '';
            var toggleSummary = showSummary ? '<p class="item-snippet">' + postContent + '</p>' : '';
            var toggleDate = showDate ? '<span class="item-date">' + shortDate + '</span>' : '';
            var toggleAuthorImg = showAuthorImg ? '' + authorImgTag + '' : '';
            var toggleCommentCount = showCommentCount ? '<span class="item-comment-count">' + postCommentCount + '</span>' : '';

            // The Output
            var itemPost = '<div class="item-post"><div class="item-imgs">' + toggleImg + toggleAuthorImg + '</div>' + toggleCommentCount + '<a class="item-link" href=' + postUrl + '>' + toggleTitle + '</a>' + toggleSummary + toggleDate + '</div>';

            // Let's Write It Down
            document.write(itemPost);
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // The Default Options
    var imgSize = 96;
    var summaryLength = 142;
    var authorImgSize = 36;
    var showImg = true; 
    var showTitle = true; 
    var showSummary = true; 
    var showDate = true;
    var showAuthorImg = true;
    var showCommentCount = true;
</script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/summary?orderby=published&amp;max-results=5&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=postGrabber"></script>
```

Comment: error message says parent of url is undefined, but question title says url is undefined?

Comment: I changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all those lines of code, the only reference I can see to a `url` property is here...

```
var orgImgUrl = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url ? json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url : 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mxinHrJWpBo/VD6fqbvI74I/AAAAAAAAcn8/LslulDeOROg/s72-c/noimage-chalkboard.jpg';
```

so, I'm guessing that what the error is saying is that `json.feed.entry[i]` doesn't have a property named `media$thumbnail`...it is "undefined". You need to correct that, whether it is a typing error or something else, make sure that that property exists.

If the property is "optional" then change your evaluation to check for the existence of that property as below...

```
var orgImgUrl = (json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail != null 
                   && json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url)
              ? json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url 
              : 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mxinHrJWpBo/VD6fqbvI74I/AAAAAAAAcn8/LslulDeOROg/s72-c/noimage-chalkboard.jpg';
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to resolve the issue. I guess I didn't write the script properly to begin with. I just assumed the property was automatically checked.